# connect to php with objective c

Tags: php, objective-c, service, web

I have never worked with web services and thought that I will try now.

I have a php file that outputs a simple string, either 1 or 0. How do I make the connection in objective c and store the php string as an NSString? If not too much, I would appreciate some example code.

I have tried searching for it on google but don't really know what to search for.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "*I have never worked with web services*" then most probably we can't help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
php -f somescript.php
```

to execute PHP script, and fetch the output.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this on Github : [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking)

Very easy to use!

For example :

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/public_timeline.json"];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {
    NSLog(@"Public Timeline: %@", JSON);
} failure:nil];
[operation start];
```

Comment: I managed to solve it by myself without the AFNetworking. Thanks for the help anyway, specially webmastx! ^^